# Non static generic types in a static context

Tags: java, generics, hashtable

I'm preparing for an interview by coding up various data structures in Java. I'm having a bit of trouble with generic types in static context though. I have a hash function that needs to be static that takes a generic parameter, but the compiler is having none of it. Any help on why this error is happening and how to better approach the problem with be appreciated.

```
public class Hashtable<K extends Comparable, T> {
    private int num_elem;
    private int num_buck;
    private ArrayList<LinkedList<Pair<K, T>>> buckets;

    private class Pair<K, T> {
        K key;
        T value;

        Pair(K key, T value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public Hashtable(int size) {
        this.num_elem = size;
        this.num_buck = (int) (num_elem * 1.2);
        this.buckets = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Pair<K, T>>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < num_buck; i++)
            buckets.add(new LinkedList<Pair<K, T>>());
    }

    public static int hash(K key) {
        return (System.identityHashCode(key) * num_buck) / 97;
    }

    public static int compress(int hashval) {
        return hashval % num_buck;
    }

    public void add(K key, T value) {
        Pair p = new Pair<K, T>(key, value);
        int hashval = Hashtable.hash(key);
        buckets.get(Hashtable.compress(key)).add(p);
    }

    public T find(K key) throws exception {
        int hashval = Hashtable.hash(key);
        LinkedList<Pair<K, T>> ll = buckets.get(Hashtable.compress(hashval));

        Iterator iter = ll.iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Pair<K, T> p = iter.Next();

            if (p.key.compareTo(key) == 0)
                return p.value;
        }

        throw new Exception("Key not in HashTable");
    }

    public void remove(K key) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Comment: "The compiler is having none of it" is not a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, you're missing the closing `}` on your `hash` method.  However, static methods can't reference the type parameter of the class, or you'll get the error:

```
non-static class K cannot be referenced from a static context
```

But it doesn't look like the `hash` method *needs* to be generic.  It should do fine taking an `Object` instead:

```
public static int hash(Object key)
```

Comment: Ah, alright. I had considered that but always shy away from using the generic Object class. I had always thought you want to avoid that. Is that the standard solution in a situation like this?

The missing bracket was a copy paste problem, I've fixed it in the post now.

Comment: Or simply `public static <K> int hash(K key)` if you really want to use generics - the type is then inferred from the parameter.

Comment: Well, you're not doing anything specific to `K` here, such as returning a `K`, so it doesn't need to be generic.

Comment: Brian: thanks, that also works and is more in line with what I wanted to do. What exactly is that syntax though, I've never seen a generic type after static before. Unfortunately, that causes another issue with a nonstatic variable (num_buck) that I can't make static. Is my approach itself to the hashtable flawed?

Comment: To use `num_buck`, pass it in as another parameter to your `hash` method.

Comment: Ah, can't believe I didn't think of that, thanks so much

Comment: @user2142343 - the syntax is covered here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html It's ... basically how you use generics with static methods. As for you second problem, yeah, I don't see why you'd make the methods static (or public) - they aren't really of use outside the class

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake using the Hashtable [dot] method syntax, since I was trying to be as clear as possible. I didn't realize that's what was causing the compiler to give an error about calling a nonstatic method form static context when using the hash function elsewhere (which is why I made it static)... Been writing in Scheme all semester and have apparently gotten rusty in Java. Thanks for all the help.